# Чем создавать отчёты

Tags: java, intellij-idea, report

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно генерировать отчёты в Intellij Idea помимо Jasper. Его использовать не получается. Часть данных разбиваю на подотчеты, и в их datasource есть запросы, которые могут вообще ничего не вернуть(пустой запрос), и в этом случае, jasper вообще ничего не отображает. Хотя должен вывести обычный текст, и вместо данных null хотя бы. Никак не могу с этим бороться.